# A subset of continuous function that take zero on a set is a closed ideal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions from $X$ to the Reals and let $X$ be compact Hausdorff. If $E \subset X$ and $k(E) = \{f \in C(X,\mathbb{R}): f(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in E \}$. Show $k(E)$ is a closed ideal.

I can show its and ideal. I'm having trouble seeing it's closed though. Thoughts?

Comment: Closed with respect to which topology?

Comment: sorry, it was sup norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $k(E)$ will be closed in any topology that implies pointwise convergence and such that $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is complete in that topology; those include in particular the one given by the supremum norm.

If $\{f_j\}\subset k(E)$ is Cauchy, then it is convergent in $C(X,\mathbb R)$. So $f_j\to f$. For any $x\in E$, 
$$
f(x)=\lim_jf_j(x)=\lim_j 0=0. 
$$
So $f\in k(E)$ and $k(E)$ is closed.